# Input blank when directive with OnChanges is used

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I am experimenting something and had this code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[wildChild]'
})
export class WildChildDirective implements OnChanges{
  @Input()
  value: string;

  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log(changes.value);
  }
}
```

My HTML code is this:

```
<input type="text"  wildChild [value]="name" />
```

### Input has value , whatever the value of {{name}} but is not displayed . Why ?

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/NGaeBPFHpXfxTb6CcbdC?p=preview

P.S. I know I can use `NgModel` but I am curious how angular works

Comment: what do you actually expect to happen?

Comment: I expect the input should have its value displayed.

Comment: well, thats one confusing thing when you try to bind things that way. what you are actually doing is binding value to html attribute called 'value' and not to dom property called 'value'. attribute is used for initializing value of input text and doesnt have effect later. what you should be doing is either regular template/reactive forms bindings or use controlvalueaccessor to access elements value dom property

Comment: It works perfectly when I remove the directive in input right. How is directive affecting the HTML element behavior , I dont understand. Yes, there are many ways to do it but I am just trying to understand what is happening here .

Comment: @Skeptor This is because angular comes with a [value] directive. By adding your directive, you are overwriting the built in directive. Try adding back your directive but changing the Input name. You'll see the native angular directive works

Comment: it works because then you reach actual input element. but when you put directive, then you reach directive but not target elements value dom property. that one you should set manualy in that case through reference to actual inout dom element. one of the things that doesnt help you here is that 'value' means 3 things here: input element attribute, input element dom property and directive input property.

Comment: what do you want? you can add FormsModule to imports, and add [(ngModel)]="name" and work perfectly, you dont remove the directive, [value] is a input property of component, you need two way data binding

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull in the element to your directive and manually assign the value to it.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[wildChild]'
})
export class WildChildDirective implements OnChanges{
  @Input()
    value: string;

    constructor(private _el: ElementRef){}

    public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
      this._el.nativeElement.value = this.value;
   }
}
```